# Ez.Newsletter.MagentoApi product_attribute.addOption

Tags: c#, magento, soap, xml-rpc

I have found the Ez.Newsletter.MagentoApi C# project on the internet.
I think its a great tool to Test the Magento SOAP API.

But after struggling with some code for WEEKS now  I decided to ask a question.

In the project, there is no sample for the `AddOption` in the `ProductAttributeOption` ([Link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.addOption.html)).

**This is the Public Method I have added to the Api solution:**

```
public static bool addOption(string apiUrl, string sessionId, object[] args)
    {
        IProductAttributeOption prox = (IProductAttributeOption)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IProductAttributeOption));
        prox.Url = apiUrl;
        return prox.addOption(sessionId, _catalog_product_attribute_add_option, args);
    }
```

**And this is the code for adding the Option:**

```
bool OptionAdded = ProductAttributeOption.addOption(apiUrl, sessionId, new object[] {
             attributeCode,
             new object[] {
                 new object[] {
                     "0", //store_id
                     "New Label Name" //value
                 },
                 "0", //orderid
                 "0"  //is_default
             }
         });
```

**But the error of the server is like:**

`An unhandled exception of type 'CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcFaultException' occurred in CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll
Additional information: Server returned a fault exception: [108] Default option value is not defined`

Comment: it has something to do with the 'is_default' option. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does any one know how to convert this code:

$label = array (
   array(
    "store_id" => array("0"),
    "value" => "some random data"
   )
  );

$data = array(
   "label" => $label,
   "order" => "10",
   "is_default" => "1"
  );

To C#

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue myself.  We use Python with Magento1.9 Xml-RPC

You're currently formatting very similar as I did initially:

```
    {'label': {'store_id': '0','value':'Purple'}, 'is_default': 0, 'order': 0}
```

After some playing around, wrapping the label value in another list did the trick:

```
    {'label': [{'store_id': '0','value':'Purple'}], 'is_default': 0, 'order': 0}
```

This is my 5cents.  Hope it helps you forward.